# How to run Add-in in background while using a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose i'm using an Add-in in my excel sheet. I have written a macro where i take input from my input sheet and paste it in the add-in and then i get the output in another sheet which should be displayed further.

The problem is when i run the macro it doesnt wait for the post processing to be done by the add in and just displays the output which was there before in those output cells.

I have tried using Wait and Sleep after pasting the input values to give some time to do the postprocessing but still it doesnt work..it gives the same output.

And it runs fine if i add a break point after pasting which helps to run the background processing but i want to run it without break point

Please Help!

```
For j = 1 To i ' loop to check if case is selected

Chk = "Chk_Case" & j
If Me.Controls(Chk).Value = True Then
' For h = 1 To j ' if case is selected, inputs will be used to generate output and will be put in datasheet
    ' to get col no of selected case
    Case_Name = Me.Controls(Chk).Caption

    Column_number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Case_Name, Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A7:K7"), 0)
    ' to get column name of selected case
    Col_Name = GetColumnName(Column_number)
    ''input range
    FinalRange = Col_Name & "8:" & Col_Name & "29"
    ''copy input and paste in sheet 1 for output
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(FinalRange).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
   'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        '''pasting output from sheet 24 to datasheet
       ' Sleep (4000)



        Application.CalculateFull
        Sheets("Sheet24").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet24").Range("B17:G39").Select
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
        Selection.Copy


       ' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:08"))


        Sheets("Datasheet").Activate
        Sheets("Datasheet").Cells(6, 14 + g).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Sheets("Datasheet").Cells(6, 14 + g).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        g = g + 6
'Next h
End If
Next j
```

Comment: What does add-in do? I mean what is suppose to happen after you paste?

Comment: There are background calculations by the add-in after the values are pasted.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.dplot.com/blog/2010/03/calling-excel-add-in-functions-from-a-macro.html)